How to add each row of a matrix to the selected rows of another matrix?
I want to achieve the following result fast
for i in range(n):
    C[index[i]] += A[i]

where C is an d * m matrix, index is an array containing n integers ranging in [0, d), and A is an n * m matrix.
I wish to find a faster, more numpy approach.

Can you provide a [mre] of the data?

Are you sure C is (d, n)? It should rather be (d, m)

Give more details, even an example or two.  For smaller dimensions your loop msy be best.  For unique indices simple indexing will work If there may be duplicates, a more complex (and slower) method is needed.

My apologies, indeed C is an d * m matrix

Assuming C is (d, m) (I don't see how it could work otherwise), you need to collect and sum the values from A in order, then add them to the correct indices in C. For that you can use argsort, unique and add.reduce:
# sort the indices in index
order = np.argsort(index)

# get the unique indices from the sorted index
# and the position of the first occurrence
idx, idx2 = np.unique(index[order], return_index=True)

C1[idx] += np.add.reduceat(A[order], idx2)

Example:
d, n, m = 4, 5, 3
np.random.seed(1)

# C is an d * m matrix
C = np.random.random((d, m))
# make copies to compare the vectorial and loop approaches
C1 = C.copy()
C2 = C.copy()

# index is an array containing n integers ranging in [0, d)
index = np.random.randint(0, d, n)
# array([3, 0, 2, 0, 1])

# A is an n * m matrix
A = np.random.random((n, m))

order = np.argsort(index)
idx, idx2 = np.unique(index[order], return_index=True)

C1[idx] += np.add.reduceat(A[order], idx2)

for i in range(n):
    C2[index[i]] += A[i]

np.allclose(C1, C2)
# True


For this small example, the for loop is faster than your reduceat.  An alternative is np.add.at(C4,index,A) which does well.  I think your unique/reduceat will shine when there are many duplicates.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but it looks to me like you can just eliminate the for loop (if the elements of index are unique, as pointed out in the comments).
import numpy as np

m, n, d = 3, 4, 5
C = np.zeros((d, m))
A = np.arange(n*m).reshape(n, m)
index = np.asarray([4, 2, 1, 0])

i = np.arange(n)
# produces the same result with or without `for i in range(n)`
C[index[i]] += A[i]
C

Produces:
array([[ 9., 10., 11.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.]])


Please try with my reproducible example, this won't work because of the potential duplicates in index (or try with index = [4, 1, 4, 0])

Sure; I'll clarify that this is if the elements of index are unique.
